# How can I change the number format in Disk Inventory X?

Tags: disk-space

I'm using Disk Inventory X to find what is taking up the most disk space, and I've noticed that it formats numbers oddly, it particular, the placement of the comma. For example: 2,01.5 GB and 1,24.8 GB.

I would much rather not have the comma at all, like this: 201.5 GB and 124.8 GB.

How can I fix this?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Disk Inventory X is version 1 released abandoned software from 11 years ago and what you're seeing is obviously a bug that you can change the behavior of.

Comment: This was asked before with a funny answer given. The dialog shows commas in the numbers instead of decimal points -- welcome to the world outside of the USA?

Comment: @norcaljohnny To be precise, the dialog is showing commas as a hundreds separator *in addition* to a decimal point separator.

Comment: @Flimm, Yes, I understood. :) That is how number systems are in a lot of countries outside the USA.

Comment: Nobody uses a hundreds separator. Only the UK & US use a comma as a thousands separator & a point for decimal. Most of the rest of the world formats with a space for thousands & a comma for decimal. It's just a bug... which will never be fixed. Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html

Answer (score 5):

The Software was updated Feb 28, 2019. The commas are placed properly.

http://www.derlien.com/